# What is the ip address that Ubuntu Advanced Package Tool (APT) calls

Tags: apt, iptables, routing

I don't fully understand what does the apt tool do under the hood.

For example, I have an Instance in cloud and I want to define out bounds rules. In order to be able install some packages i.e. `apt install zip` I allow the ports 80 and 443. However, currently I am allowing it for all ips `0.0.0.0`. Is there any standart ip to allow the outbond trafic only to the ubuntu package mangement server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Basically, `apt` contacts the servers in your package repositories / sources list, see [The Debian documentation on apt sources](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList):

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://site.example.com/debian distribution component1 component2 component3
```

Here are the sites, e.g. `site.example.com` port 80 above.  More could be in the files contained in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

You could make DNS lookups for these, perhaps copy the IP addresses to `/etc/hosts` so that they will not change too often (in case servers have a number of IP addresses for load balancing), then the list is short and you do not need to allow DNS lookups:

```
$ nslookup site.example.com
(...)
Name:   site.example.com
Address: 11.22.33.44
$ echo "11.22.33.44 site.example.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

(Of course this assumes that servers will stay available at those addresses but if not you will see error messages in update attempts.)